# How to hand over a local var to another method in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, var, valuetuple

I have got a deserialization method which returns a `ValueTuple<String[],String[],String[,],String[,],String[,]>`:

```
var des = deserializeobject(filename);
```

Now I would like to work with these arrays within the method

```
public static void oDocX();
```

How can I hand over the local variable `des` to the method `oDocX`?

Comment: convert it to global?

Comment: Add a parameter to your oDocX methods. Visual Studio may tell you what the actual type of des is.

Comment: Your object ref to oDocX needs to implement a method or property so you can pass it in.

Comment: How about changing the signature to `public static void oDocX(ValueTuple<String[],String[],String[,],String[,],String[,]> values);`?

Answer (score 2):

Either have a variable at class level:

```
class YourClass
{
    private static ValueTuple<String[],String[],String[,],String[,],String[,]> _des;

    // some methods

    public static void oDocX() {...}
}
```

and then assign it like this:

```
_des = deserializeobject(filename);
```

and use it like this in `oDocX`:

```
public static void oDocX()
{
    var x = _des;
}
```

---

Or take it as a parameter of `oDocX`:

```
public static void oDocX(ValueTuple<String[],String[],String[,],String[,],String[,]> des)
{
    var x = des;
}
```

And call the method like this:

```
var des = deserializeobject(filename);
oDocX(des);
```